# Using a string stream to fill a vector of integers

Tags: c++

This is a code snippet from a program that asks for inputs in a loop which is pretty bulky and hard to sift through so I limited my post to this snippet. This should be reading the inputs of some number of integers into the vector iin.
For some reason, when the program completes its first loop, the next loop which asks for a character, recieves the last few numbers that were entered in the first loop. I take the inputs at the beginning of the loop with cin, so somehow the end of my string stream is going into cin at the beginning of the next loop?
Not sure where to go from here.

I have looked at many many posts here that execute this same strategy but I can't see any part of those posts which I have missed.

```
        cout << "Please enter command parameters: ";
        string in;
        int temp;
        cin >> in;
        istringstream input(in);
        while(input>>temp){
            iin.push_back(temp);
            input.clear();
        }
```

Sorry for not making a proper example code.

Here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Functions.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
bool quit=false,filewrite=false,filein=false;
char cmd;
std::vector<int> iin;
std::vector<double> din;


extern ofstream ofile;
extern ifstream ifile;

int main(){
    while(!quit){
        cout << "Please enter command code: ";
        cin >> cmd;
        cout << "Please enter command parameters: ";
        string in;
        int temp;
        cin >> in;
        istringstream input(in);
        while(input>>temp){
            iin.push_back(temp);
            input.clear();
        }
        // call functions after, one of them will trigger quit
}
}
```

Running this code results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsW1U.png) for me.

Sorry I don't have the ability to embed yet.

OK! I have resolved it.

Realized my inputs have spaces so in was only ever recieving first character, as was pointed out in the comments. This:

```
            cout << "Please enter command parameters: ";
            char inp[256];
            int temp;
            cin.getline(inp,256);
            string strin(inp);
            istringstream ss(strin);
            while(ss>>temp){
                cout << temp << endl;
                iin.push_back(temp);
            }
```

Gives me the right result. Initially this method didn't work because I had used cin previously, which resulted in me needing to use cin.ignore() to clear the buffer. Not too sure on this explanation since I just barely came up with the solution but hopefully it's useful to someone. Cheers!

Comment: If you read into a `std::string` using the stream extraction operator, the stream will only read up to a whitespace character and then stop. If you want to read multiple integers, you might want to use `std::getline` to read the string before handing it to the `stringstream`.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a seg fault error now.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm not sure I can help with that. Can you post a minimal, self-contained example that we can use to reproduce the error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that duplicates the error.  Otherwise all one can say is that you have bugs in your code and you should fix them.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added it.

Comment: Your example appears to work fine (except it only reads one integer value for the reason  @templatetypedef described. It's likely that the code you omitted is the real problem. What input are you actually giving?

Comment: This reproduces my error. Entering something like: 4 5 6, results in extra inputs being read for the command code.

Comment: Beyond that any other method I try results in a seg fault error before any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

What about formatted input if you know you are only getting int.

`int i;
cin >> i;
v.push_back(i);`

Or c style

`int i;
Scanf("%d", &i);
v.push_back(i);`

Answer (score -2):

```
string in;
        int temp;
        cin >> in;
        istringstream input(in);
        while(input>>temp)
```

Here you use two data types one is `string` and other is `integer`. You use string inside the input and then compare `input` from `integer` variable. First you do not initialize `temp` variable with any number and second you can not compare `string` with `integer`.

Hopefully you understand your mistake.

Comment: Your answer makes *no sense* whatsoever.

Comment: Hmmm it seems like you don't understand this code. Input is a stringstream and the operator >> directs formatted output to temp. The formatted output can be an int. It is essentially the same as cin >> variable.